# Stuttering and audio distortion on new build

Tags: windows-10, audio, graphics-card, freeze, computer-building

After building and installing Windows 10 (64-bit, Anniversary update), I get frequent and very quick freezing/stuttering. I can just move the mouse back and forth on the desktop, or more easily see it by playing a YouTube video or a game. Only pattern I've noticed is it happens when first starting up/logging in (mouse lags on desktop) or within the first few moments of playing a YouTube video. No CPU, memory, or temperature issues when this happens.

[Here's a short video showing the issue while playing a YouTube video.](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOjFVSwptotGqPG5UWpA2w2gvmqt5-9miI3LWJiBkCJQExTiA_S7eaEJzOQUEQIvQ/photo/AF1QipNkNIrwZowsEJT1brQj7O9PoSAQC9eHSQ8X0ro?key=bjlsckJUODJqTm01WXNEQWFtMzBoMGNCNXVfMS1n)

### Parts list

PCPartPicker part list: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/FDb76X
Price breakdown by merchant: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/FDb76X/by_merchant/

- CPU: Intel Core i5-7600K 3.8GHz Quad-Core Processor
- CPU Cooler: Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO 82.9 CFM Sleeve Bearing CPU Cooler
- Motherboard: Asus PRIME Z270-AR ATX LGA1151 Motherboard
- Memory: Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR4-3000 Memory
- Storage: Samsung 840 EVO 250GB 2.5" Solid State Drive
- Storage: Samsung 850 EVO-Series 500GB 2.5" Solid State Drive
- Video Card: EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 8GB Superclocked Gaming ACX 3.0 Video Card
- Case: Corsair Carbide 400C ATX Mid Tower Case
- Power Supply: SeaSonic 760W 80+ Platinum Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply
- Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro OEM 64-bit
- Monitor: Acer XB270HU bprz 27.0" 2560x1440 144Hz Monitor
- Keyboard: Corsair K70 LUX RGB Wired Gaming Keyboard
- Mouse: Corsair M65 RGB Wired Laser Mouse

### Things I've tried

- Flashed BIOS to latest.
- Loaded BIOS defaults.
- Performed Windows Memory Diagnostic (no problems).
- Tried with built-in Realtek HD audio disabled in BIOS.
- Disabled Nvidia HD Audio device.
- Disabled Windows indexing on drives.
- Set power profile to High Performance.
- Verified SATA controller in AHCI mode.
- Verified up-to-date firmware on SSDs.
- Verified no SMART issues.
- Tried different DDR4 3000 memory.
- Tried different video card (my old GTX 970)
- Tried different SSD/HDD.
- Tried different PSU.
- Tried with mobo and GPU drivers.
- Tried WITHOUT any additional drivers after a fresh reinstall.
- Installed pending Windows Updates.
- Disconnected all USB except for KB/mouse

### Relevant photos

[Build picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v503o.jpg)
[Temps and Performance tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiYwN.jpg)

Comment: Use this to capture a log of the Audio issues: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matthew_van_eerde/2017/01/09/collecting-audio-logs-the-old-fashioned-way/ Compress the ETL as 7z and share it (onedrive, dropbox)

Comment: Nice use of PCPartPicker.com!  I haven't seen it used that way before, but it makes absolute sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling ASUS support, I ended up returning and exchanging the motherboard for a new one.

Comment: On your computer the memory controller is not located on the motherboard but rather on the processor itself.

Comment: Im having the exact same problem. Did replacing mobo fix your issue?

Comment: @ben yes, I ended up replacing the board.